# Link to a sample of a charting or scheduling control

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm looking for a component that I can use to plot class times against a timeline for four different instructors.  So the y axis will contain a timeline at 30 minute intervals, with the instructors class times stacked in one column per instructor.  Any idea what control I should look at using?  I thinking the MS Chart control stacked column chart may be the solution - not really sure how to set this up...anyone know of a link or example similar to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does it need to be free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart Control for .NET Framework enables you to add robust charting abilities to your applications with little effort. It is a fully managed .NET Framework component and has been specifically designed for use with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

For examples of how to use Chart Control for .NET Framework, download the samples on Codeplex. Also, to access community content, go to the Chart Control Forum.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=128713

Comment: Range bar or Range column chart type of the MS Chart Controls was what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) a few time with success.  Use the google machine, I think there are even [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtg0DcplJEc) out there on how to use it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple charting component is to use the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Chart

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx

It comes standard in the .NET 4.0 framework -- otherwise you can download a the assemblies here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en

I use this chart control frequently and have built other components on top of it. It's very straightforward to use and supports databinding